# Adjust xml layout for ListView which has imaage and text

Tags: android, xml, image, android-layout, listview

Can someone please help me to adjust my `xml` layout ? In **Edit_Staff** activity, I wanted to retrieve the image and text from SQLite and load them into `listView` by using code below.

**Edit_Staff**

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Claimtype"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Claims Type : "
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable"
            android:text="Amount : "
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Claimtype" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable"
            android:text="Description : "
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/amount" />/>

    </RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the issue? What is there to adjust?

Comment: @Ron I want the imageView in the left hand side, text at right.

Comment: You can try this: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html

Comment: @Ron no. I know how to create a listView, but I don't know how to make the xml layout to something like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=list+view+with+image+and+text&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=955&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJz-OF6tjJAhUCwI4KHZVaAkEQ_AUIBygC#imgrc=1F-rfqdLvvJnmM%3A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest row you can do is something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="start"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:padding="12dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/your_drawable_here"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    app:civ_border_width="1dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_time"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Itemname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="Testing"
        android:maxLines="1"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemSubtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable"
        android:text="This is a long message"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"

        android:layout_below="@+id/Itemname"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_time"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="8sp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="lala"
    android:padding="2dip"
    />
```

Comment: Just substitute some of your own sizes and text elements as you need.